# How to map through State and push results into a second Axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, object, mapping

Really getting stuck with this one.  I'm building a simple ReactJS web app, where you can:

1. Search for a city
2. Axios GET request fourSquare api and return recommend venues.

Simple!  Only thing is, this public api for venue results, no longer includes photos!

Here's my axios request:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=london&&client_id=JUTTZIYT3Y2ECNHCORRDKIPLW1FNSAH2PW0XRLJCMIPRKY1Q&client_secret={REMOVED_CLIENT_SECRET}&v=201806044&venuePhotos=1

```
  componentDidMount() {
       console.log('COMPONENT DID MOUNT');

       axios.get('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=london&&client_id=JUTTZIYT3Y2ECNHCORRDKIPLW1FNSAH2PW0XRLJCMIPRKY1Q&client_secret={REMOVED_CLIENT_SECRET}&v=201806044&venuePhotos=1')
      .then(res => {
           console.log('DATA', res.data.response.groups[0].items);
           this.setState(
           { places: res.data.response.groups[0].items.slice(0,12)});
       });
  }
```

I'm then passing my venues results, into another component/page and looping through all the data. Such as Name, Address etc.

```
  return (
    <section className="">
      <h2 className="title has-text-centered">Heres what we recommend in London</h2>
      <div className="columns is-multiline">
        {places.map((place, i) => <div className="column is-one-quarter" key={i}>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div className="card-image">
                <figure className="image">
                  <h2 className="has-text-centered has-text-grey">Venue: {place.venue.name}</h2>
                  <h2 className="has-text-centered has-text-grey">Category: {place.venue.categories[0].pluralName}</h2>
                  <h2 className="has-text-centered has-text-grey">Why?: {place.reasons.items[0].summary}</h2>
                  <p className="has-text-centered has-text-link">Address: {place.venue.location.formattedAddress}</p>
                  <p className="has-text-centered has-text-link">ID: {place.venue.id}</p>
                  {/* <img className="animated rotateIn" src={place.venue.categories[0].icon.prefix.concat(place.venue.categories[0].icon.suffix)}/> */}
                </figure>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>)}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The only thing is, in order to get a venue location photo, I then have to parse the venue ID into a second API request. Such as this one:

[https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE ID GOES HERE/photos?client_id=JUTTZIYT3Y2ECNHCORRDKIPLW1FNSAH2PW0XRLJCMIPRKY1Q&client_secret={REMOVED_CLIENT_SECRET}&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4ac518d2f964a52026a720e3/photos?client_id=JUTTZIYT3Y2ECNHCORRDKIPLW1FNSAH2PW0XRLJCMIPRKY1Q&client_secret=%7BREMOVED_CLIENT_SECRET%7D&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74)

I can map through the venue ID fine in my JSX.  But I don't know how to store it from the JSX.

Outside the JSX, lets say in a function component, I can't seem to loop/map through the data to get to venue Id.  I think this is because it's an object.

Here's a screenshot, of how I'm looping through my data so far.  And console shows the ID I'm trying to get to and push into a second request...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWoEA.jpg

Any ideas on how I can grab that ID and push it onto a second axios request?

Comment: Just nest a second axios request?

Comment: If you make an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) I'll take a look for you.

Comment: You can just create another Component like `<CardImage />` which encapsulates your `<div className="card-image">` and receives all the venue data. And then you simply does as you did on this bigger component, do the axios call using the id on the `componentDidMount()` :)